# PuTTY not working on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu

PuTTY always just worked for me, and I've never had a moment's bother with it until now. Since upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04 LTS it hasn't worked. I have purged it from the system and reinstalled, but the result is the same. When I try to SSH to one of the sites on which it worked perfectly previously, now it simply disappears as soon as I press "open".

Can anyone help me get my old pal PuTTY back again?

Comment: try running it in a terminal. Without sudo, just type `putty`. I suspect it segfaults, in which case the clear message will be printed. In this case you can try to remove its configuration and build it from a scratch. Honestly, putty was never very usable under Linux, so consider switching to openssh's ssh client, which is much more convenient to use, so it is even provided as a Windows feature.

Comment: Do you run a current version of Putty? Encryption/handshaking requirements may have been upgraded with Ubuntu 22.04.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. Go to Putty Configuration --> Window --> Fonts. Define as 'Font used for ordinary text' another font that is listed and previewed without problem (eg Ubuntu Mono).